# Cursor is blinking on tabs

Tags: bug, user-interface, design

I don't know why but my mouse always finds that damned pixel on the edge of *tabs* in SO design when the cursor starts to blink. And that is really irritating!

[image: Blinking cursor]

<sub>(Not the best GIF but the main point is visible)</sub>

*Found in*: profile, questions, review, and other sections with tabs.

*Browsers*: Chrome, IE. FF has the same effect on mouse move.

Comment: How? How the heck that question was not in the search? :(

Comment: I know what I'm doing this afternoon..... Weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee....

Comment: @Bart What I was doing is trying to capture that GIF animation.. in vain! And the bad thing is that nothing was changed from 2009.

Comment: Lol I went a step further from GIF and recorded [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgFLozCxqlM)! ;)

Comment: Must add that for some odd reason Nick marked it as "completed" while it's not.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd How do you think have I done GIF? :) Downloaded some weird capturer, installed it on my office laptop (no admin rights!), captured AVI, uploaded to some random online converter... I haven't used YouTube only ;) Regarding the tag, it seems to be reproduced now.

Comment: @Bart Looks like you've captured a video with your iPhone camera :)

Comment: :) Nah, just @ShaWizDowArd's video converted to gif.

Comment: @Bart wow YouTubgification! :D