# Visual bug on "featured" tabs mouse-over

Tags: bug, bountied-tab

When I mouse-over the featured tabs on both Stack Overflow main and here on Meta, the height of the box around the number seems to change. It shrinks from both the bottom and the top, and annoyingly "runs into" the top border of the tab. Is this supposed to happen? I find it annoying and distracting, especially how it meets the border on the top.

**UPDATE: This happens to any tab with the number box in it including reputation/response/etc. tabs on my profile page.**

I'm using Google Chrome 25 on Linux.

Google Chrome 25 on Linux: [image]

Google Chrome 25 on Mac: [image] (still shrinks, but doesn't run into the top)

Comment: You mean [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171467/152859)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No... Perhaps a picture would be helpful.

Comment: Reproduced the bug.

Comment: Adding "bump" tag is NOT proper way to bump a question. This tag is meant for questions related to the bump process itself.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you for letting me know. Is there a recommended way to bump a question?

Comment: Proper edit (e.g. add new details) otherwise bounty.

Comment: Is this still happening?