# Faulty CSS gave my mouse an epileptic fit and killed my browser!

Tags: bug, design

I just went outside for a cigarette, came back, and noticed a dead Chrome window. I started Chrome with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, which meant my cursor stayed in position, which led me to what caused this.

Unfortunately a screenshot can't capture what's going on in time, but here's a 30 second, unlisted YouTube video to demonstrate the problem:

http://youtu.be/OrzVhuMVNm4

Pay attention to my cursor - apparently I managed to leave my mouse hovered over the ONE vertical pixel that would cause this. Also, when not recording the screen, the cursor swaps between normal and pointer a LOT faster.

This effects all tabs, except the active one.

Comment: @Oded I agree this is definitely related, but it isn't an *exact* dupe, per se. Moreover, it **killed my browser**! 3 years later, a bounty, and a working solution posted over a year ago (in the dupe link), and this *still* can't be fixed?!

Comment: +1 for being patient enough to have it kill the browser!

Comment: If you want a more recent one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171467/cursor-is-blinking-on-tabs